# URLRewriter works on localhost but not on the server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I used these roles on the localhost (ASP.NET 4) and it works:

```
  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/man/(.+)" to="~/man/$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="~/man/^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|\.axd)(\?.+)?)$" to="~/man/$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="~/files/^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|\.axd|\.pdf|\.doc|\.ppt)(\?.+)?)$" to="~/files/$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="~/man/" to="~/man/default.aspx" processing="stop"/>
    <rewrite url="~/style/(.+)" to="~/style/$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="~/images/(.+)" to="~/images/$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|\.axd)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="~/register.aspx" to="~/register.aspx" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="~/(.+)" to="~/default.aspx?pn=$1" />
  </rewriter>
```

For example, `http://localhost/myweb/foo` refers to `http://localhost/myweb/default.aspx?pn=foo` but on the web server `http://myweb.xx/foo` says `'404 - File or directory not found.'`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IIS are there is Server because in II6 there is different way and in II7 There is different way.

Answer (score 0):

Check in which section of your Web.Config you have configured your rules, as System.web is used for VS Development Server ("Cassini") and IIS6  and System.WebServer is used for IIS7.

You can also take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx)

Comment: I've IIS7 on localhost and IIS 7.5 on the server

Comment: Can you paste a bit more information of your web.Config, specially the system.web and system.webserver sections? also, do you have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" ?

Comment: Yes I have, I changed the expression then it worked! changed to this: <rewrite url="/(.+)" to="~/default.aspx?pn=$1" /> if you write it as answer I'll mark this as answer.